# Select statement with group_concat not working when other columns are called in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hello my laravel code is

```
$productDetails = DB::table('products')
        ->select(DB::raw('products.name, GROUP_CONCAT(sizes.name) as sizesName'))
        ->join('subcategories', 'products.subcategories_id', '=', 'subcategories.id')
        ->join('size_categories', 'subcategories.categories_id', '=', 'size_categories.categories_id')
        ->join('sizes',function($join){
            $join->on(DB::raw("FIND_IN_SET(sizes.id, size_categories.size_id)"),">",DB::raw("'0'"));
         })
        ->where('products.id', $request->id)
        ->get();
```

This doesnt work, when i use`products.name or any other column name in select statement`
but when i use only group_concat inside Db::raw and nothing else, the query works.
So how do i fetch other columns?
Please help.
I am stuck on it for quite a while
The query i want is

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(sizes.name),`products`.`name`, `products`.`image`, `products`.`id`, `products`.`image_second`, `products`.`description`, `products`.`min_order`, `size_categories`.`size_id` from `products` 
inner join `subcategories` on `products`.`subcategories_id` = `subcategories`.`id`
 inner join `size_categories` on `subcategories`.`categories_id` = `size_categories`.`categories_id`
 join sizes on (FIND_IN_SET(sizes.id,size_categories.size_id)>0) where `products`.`id` = '7'
```

Please note that the above query is working fine. I just cant make it in laravel to work. Only the group_concat part.

This is the screenshot from my database, when i dont use group_concat
[image]

Also the DISTINCT part is doing nothing there, please ignore it.
I was just trying that out

This is the migration of create_products_table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('units_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('selections_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('subcategories_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->string('min_order');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->index('units_id');
            $table->index('selections_id');
            $table->index('subcategories_id');
        });
    }
```

migration of create_subcategories_table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('subcategories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('categories_id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->index('categories_id');
        });
    }
```

data of size_categories table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('size_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('size_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('categories_id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->index('categories_id');
        });
    }
```

migration of categories table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

migration of sizes table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('sizes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

In sizes table data is in this form

```
id   name   
1    2m   
2    3m
3    4m
```

Comment: User separate `DB::raw` for each. As in `DB::raw('products.name'), DB::raw(' GROUP_CONCAT(sizes.name) as sizesName')`

Comment: sir, i changed it to this `->select(DB::raw('products.name'), DB::raw(' GROUP_CONCAT(sizes.name) as sizesName'))` , still nothing

Comment: share your migrations and some test data, I'll give it a go.

Comment: Sir. I edited the question, i have a query which is working fine. As per the data. If you still need my table data, please tell me i will share everything about my tables

Comment: In that case enable query log on laravel and see if the produced query is the same as your working query. That would be the easiest way to work towards debugging, imo.

Comment: Sir i have added a screenshot of my database, i want to group_concat sizes.name

Comment: I cant do anything with a screenshot. If you would share your migrations I would be more than happy try it at my end. But, did you check query log? I suggest you check that first, your query produced by Laravel should be the same/similar to the working query you have.

Comment: sir i added DB::connection()->enableQueryLog(); in my function, but its showing invalid function. i also tried dd($products), it isnt showing anything as it is an ajax request. Also as you said i added migrations and data. Please check it out , Thank You

Comment: I hope this data was enough for you to try it out, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218618/discussion-between-user3532758-and-shah-rukh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to specify select columns separately. Like so:

```
->select(DB::raw('products.name'), DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(sizes.name) as sizesName'))
```

Next, since group concat is an aggregate column, you need to group the sizes, and product name since it's in the select list and it is not related to size.

```
->groupBy('size_categories.size_id', 'products.id') //edit after your comment. group by prodcuts.id to be able to select columns from products table.
```

So your final query should look like this:

```
$productDetails = DB::table('products')
        ->select(DB::raw('products.name'), DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(sizes.name) as sizesName'))
        ->join('subcategories', 'products.subcategories_id', '=', 'subcategories.id')
        ->join('size_categories', 'subcategories.categories_id', '=', 'size_categories.categories_id')
        ->join('sizes',function($join){
            $join->on(DB::raw("FIND_IN_SET(sizes.id, size_categories.size_id)"),">",DB::raw("'0'"));
         })
        ->where('products.id', 7)
        ->groupBy('size_categories.size_id', 'products.id')
        ->get();
```